RaspberryPi上でC言語の独立動作させたい
このコードはRaspberryPi上の液晶モニターで茶色のタクトスイッチを押したら上の行にhelloを表示してボタンを離したら1秒表示を続ける、赤色のタクトスイッチを押したら下の行にworldを表示してボタンを離したら1秒表示を続けるプログラムになっています。しかし片方が動作中のときにもう片方のタクトスイッチを押すと表示が同時に消えてしまいます。本来2つの表示は独立に動作させたいのです。一応マルチスレッドを作るべきか考えていますが、実際にどのようなコードにすればよいかわかりません。どのようにしたらよいか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願い致します。
include.c
#include "include.h"

void *gpio_baseaddr;

unsigned int memread(void *baseaddr, int offset){
    unsigned int *p;
    p = baseaddr+offset;
    return *p;  // read memory-mapped register
}

void memwrite(void *baseaddr, int offset, unsigned int x){
    unsigned int *p;
    p = baseaddr+offset;
    *p = x; // write memory-mapped register
}

void ledOnOff(){
    unsigned int gpfsel0;
    gpfsel0= memread(gpio_baseaddr, GPIO_GPFSEL0);  // get GPIO5 mode
    gpfsel0 = gpfsel0 | (1<<15);        // 15=GPIO5*3, bit15 ON
    memwrite(gpio_baseaddr, GPIO_GPFSEL0, gpfsel0); // GPIO5 output mode
    memwrite(gpio_baseaddr, GPIO_GPSET0, (1 << 5)); // GPIO5 high
    sleep(1);
    memwrite(gpio_baseaddr, GPIO_GPCLR0, (1 << 5)); // GPIO5 low
}

int lcd_cmdwrite(int fd, unsigned char dat){
    unsigned char buff[2];
    buff[0] = 0;
    buff[1] = dat;
    return write(fd,buff,2);
}

int lcd_datawrite(int fd, char dat[]){
    int len;
    char buff[100];

    len = strlen(dat);  // don't count EOS (Null char)
    if (len>99) {printf("too long string\n"); exit(1); }
    memcpy(buff+1, dat, len);   // shift 1 byte, ignore EOS
    buff[0] = 0x40; // DATA Write command
    return write(fd, buff, len+1);
}

void initLCD(int fd){
    int i;
    unsigned char init1[]={ 0x38, 0x39, 0x14, 0x70, 0x56, 0x6c };
    unsigned char init2[]={ 0x38, 0x0c, 0x01 };

    usleep(100000); // wait 100ms
    for (i=0;i<sizeof(init1)/sizeof(unsigned char);i++) {
        if(lcd_cmdwrite(fd, init1[i])!=2){
            printf("internal error1\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        usleep(50); // wait 50us
    }

    usleep(300000); // wait 300ms

    for (i=0;i<sizeof(init2)/sizeof(unsigned char);i++) {
        if(lcd_cmdwrite(fd, init2[i])!=2){
            printf("internal error2\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        usleep(50);
    }
    usleep(2000);   // wait 2ms
}

int location(int fd, int y){
    int x = 0;
    int cmd=0x80 + y * 0x40 + x;
    int a = 0xbe;
    return lcd_cmdwrite(fd, cmd);
}

keydisp.c(メイン)
#include "include.h"
int flag_b = 0;
int flag_r = 0;

void signal_handler(int signum) {
    if(flag_b == 0){flag_b = 1;}
    if(flag_r == 0){flag_r = 1;}
}

int main(){
    //何もしてない 2fc0c1ff
    //茶色押してる 2f80c1ff
    //赤色押してる 2f40c1ff
    void *gpio_baseaddr;
    int i2c = open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR);
    if (i2c < 0) {
        perror("i2c perror");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ioctl(i2c, I2C_SLAVE, 0x3e) < 0) {
        perror("slave perror");
        exit(1);
    }

    initLCD(i2c);

    int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Failed to open /dev/mem perror");
        close(i2c);
        exit(1);
    }
    gpio_baseaddr = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, GPIO_PHY_BASEADDR);
    if (gpio_baseaddr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap failed perror");
        close(fd);
        close(i2c);
        exit(1);
    }

    struct itimerval timval;
    timval.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    timval.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    timval.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    timval.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    
    signal(SIGALRM, signal_handler);

    while (1) {
        unsigned int mr_b = ((memread(gpio_baseaddr, GPIO_GPLEV0) & (~0x2f80c1ff)) >> 22);
        unsigned int mr_r = ((memread(gpio_baseaddr, GPIO_GPLEV0) & (~0x2f40c1ff)) >> 23);
        if (mr_b == 0) {
            location(i2c, 0);
            int val = lcd_datawrite(i2c, "hello");
            if (val < 0) {
                perror("datawrite");
                break;
            }
            if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timval, NULL) < 0) {
                perror("timer");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag_b == 1) {
            if(mr_b == 0){
                location(i2c, 0);
                int val = lcd_datawrite(i2c, "hello");
                if (val < 0) {
                    perror("datawrite");
                    break;
                }

                if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timval, NULL) < 0) {
                    perror("timer");
                    break;
                }
            }
            location(i2c, 0);
            int val = lcd_datawrite(i2c, "     ");
            if (val < 0) {
                perror("datawrite");
                break;
            }
            flag_b = 0;
        }
        if (mr_r == 0) {
            location(i2c, 1);
            int val = lcd_datawrite(i2c, "world");
            if (val < 0) {
                perror("datawrite");
                break;
            }
            if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timval, NULL) < 0) {
                perror("timer");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag_r == 1) {
            if(mr_r == 0){
                location(i2c, 1);
                int val = lcd_datawrite(i2c, "world");
                if (val < 0) {
                    perror("datawrite");
                    break;
                }
                if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timval, NULL) < 0) {
                    perror("timer");
                    break;
                }
            }
            location(i2c, 1);
            int val = lcd_datawrite(i2c, "     ");
            if (val < 0) {
                perror("datawrite");
                break;
            }
            flag_r = 0;
        }
    }
    close(i2c);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}


対象装置(Raspberry PiもLCDも)に色々な種類があるらしいのでそれが何かといった情報も追記した方が良いと思われます。Raspberry Pi 3B でI2CなLCDを使う, Raspi Picoで Grove LCD を使う (C++), RaspberryPi Pico + ILI9341 (3.2インチ) LCD で Hello, World, Raspberry Pi 応用編 そしてスイッチの読み取りが如何とかではなくて文字の表示で使っている機能・コマンドがどのような仕様なのかを調べた方が良いのでは？ (ディスプレイ全部をいったんクリアしてから書くとかになっていませんか？)

そもそも独立動作させたい、というところから設計が間違ってます
あなたのその考えている動作を実現すべく、一つのコードで実装させましょう

しかし片方が動作中のときにもう片方のタクトスイッチを押すと表示が同時に消えてしまいます。

まずはなぜ今のコードでこんな事になってしまうのかの原因を究明していきましょう。
くれぐれも、独立動作させたい、という都合の良い考え方してる限りは問題は解決できません。

なぜマイナスついているのか不思議。この例の場合 LCD 資源は１つしかないので排他が必要だからマルチスレッド化する意義がほとんどまったくないっス。急いでマルチスレッドとか排他とか難しいこと学ぶよりはシングルスレッドで普通にコード書くことを考えるほうが１００倍有意義だと思われるっス。マイナスモデ付けた人の理由とか是非聞いてみたい。
